# How to create a metadata json member for an openlayers layers object and display in extjs grid?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I want to do the following: add

```
metadata: "this is the layer metadata"
```

....to my openlayers layer config.

This should then be presented in an extjs grid. I can use

```
alert(layername.metadata);
```

to display the string inside the config member so I know it works.

To display this in the extjs grid I have used the following code

```
var myData = [];
var x=mapPanel.map.layers;
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  // alert(mapPanel.map.layers[i].metadata);
    myData.push(mapPanel.map.layers[i].metadata);
}

var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: [
           {name: 'metadata'}
        ]
        });

store.loadData(myData);

var myStore = new GeoExt.data.LayerStore({
    map: map,
    layers: mapPanel.layers
}); 

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        title: "Available Map Layers",
        region: "center",
        height: 300,
        viewConfig: {forceFit: true},
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                header: "metadata",
                dataIndex: "metadata",
                sortable: true
            }
        ]
    });

var metadataWin = new Ext.Window({
                title: "Map layers",
                layout: 'fit',
                width: '600',
                height: 'auto',
                border: false,
                closable: true,
                collapsible: true,
                x: 450,
                y: 100,
                resizable: true,
                closeAction: 'hide',
                plain: true,
                items: [grid]
           });
    metadataWin.show();
```

the grid show the correct amount of rows, but only the first letter is shown....this is probably a newbie javascript error.

Can anyone see where i´m going wrong?

yours,

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done adding this metadata with this following code:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Building", {
    stylemap: styles,
    visibility: false,
    rangeOfZoom: '9-12',
    metadata: 'write What you Want'
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

and you can reach all layer's metadata as ...:

```
var layers = map.layers;
for(var a = 0; a < layers.length; a++){
   alert(layers[a].metadata)
};
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have basically come up with the same thing but instead of displaying the metadata in an alert I would like to build an array and display them using an ext.grid